# Iterate through checkboxes in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Jinja2 template that looks like this:

```
<form action="" method=post>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        {% for page in pages %}
            <tr>
                <td><input type=checkbox name=do_delete value="{{ page['id'] }}"></td>
                <td>{{ page['id'] }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ page['id'] }}">{{ page['title'] }}</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    With selected:
    <input type=submit value=Delete>
</form>
```

And I have a function, that should delete the pages according to which checkboxes were checked, when the 'Delete' button is clicked:

```
db.session.query(Page).filter(Page.id.in_(page_ids)).delete()
```

What I'm stuck with is how do I iterate through all the checkboxes and form the `page_ids` list of checked ones.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Flask's `request` object (well, actually the class that is returned by the `LocalProxy` instance that is `request`) is a subclass of werkzeug's [`MultiDict`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict) data structure - which includes a [`getlist`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) method.

```
page_ids = request.form.getlist("do_delete")
```